# 2D platform game camera in c++

Tags: c++, camera

I was wondering how exactly cameras are programmed in a 2D platform game. How is it programmed only to render whats in the view of the camera without rendering the whole map? Also, whats the proper way to do this?

Comment: If your making a game engine in OpenGL you should use `gluLookAt`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have looked for SDL and found out that a camera can also be created with SDL_Rect. Now that I am in a good lead, I should be able to find my way out of this issue. I am still curious though in knowing exactly how those cameras work, any source to explain this would be appreciated.

Comment: This should probably go to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Lazy foo has some good tutorials on this subject and further http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/index.php
navigate to the scrolling tutorial, its in c++ with SDL but the logic should be universal.

Answer (score -1):

There is no secret about that, you can simple check which tiles and which sprites are inside the rectangle that defines the screen and only draw those.

Another trick is to make the cameras always follows the player, but when it gets to the corner of the scenario you stop moving the camera, so you do not show the scenario borders.